What feedback does Beat Saber give on how well I hit notes?
I'm usually able to tell if I hit a note for several reasons (sound, vibration, score instead of a "miss" notice, continued combo), but it's hard to tell how well I'm hitting notes. The score gives a little information (being an aggregate of angle plus centering adding up to a maximum of 115), but it's hard to read. Are there any other hints as to how well I'm hitting notes, such as the type of sound effect?

Vanilla options
Beat Saber by default has:

Underlines: When you hit a block perfectly through the center, there is an underline under the score. Therefore, a score of 113 with an underline means that the center was hit, but there were 2 points of underswing. A score of 113 without an underline indicates you were off center by at least 1 point (either 2 points off center or 1 point off center and 1 point of underswing—you don't know if you had any underswing unless you scored below 100).

Advanced HUD: Enabling this in Player Settings shows your percentage for the whole song. For example, if you have a 90%, you will get SS rank (barely) and you're averaging a score of approximately 104 per note (with a miss counting as 0).
Small Notes & Pro Mode: These modifiers change the gameplay, making it harder to hit notes because they are smaller. Small Notes decreases the visual appearance of notes considerably and the size of the hitbox a little. Pro Mode sets the hitbox of the note to be the same size as the note appears to be. These modifiers (either alone or together) can help increase accuracy because (in addition to the visual effect), they turn near-misses into actual misses, which is strong feedback itself (and works well with other modifiers, like 1 Life).

I was never able to figure out if there was a meaning to each sound, or any other subtle effects. However, practically speaking that means none of these would be helpful cues.
Mod options
Since this isn't much information, many players use mods to get more specific feedback. For example:

HitScoreVisualizer. (See also the online preview.) This mod is very re-configurable, so I'll only explain the default config:

Colors (and text size) based on what range the score falls into (e.g., blue by default is 110–114 and is 120% size)
A plus sign to indicate enough swing, and a minus sign to indicate underswing. The sign on the left is pre-swing, right is post-swing.
Underlines for accuracy.



Replay mods, such as Replay. This enables replays in BeatLeader that can be seen in VR or on the website. When viewing in VR, you can see the effects added by other mods and the replay speed can be changed.


There are other mods out there, but this is what I've used on Quest 2.

Hey Laurel, good answer you posted. I don’t know if you know this, but you can also mark your own answer as accepted, which you should probably do, since it lets people know your problem's been solved and so that other people also know this works.
